# Getting an error while trying to run PostgreSQL in container on GitHub Actions runner

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest, github-actions, fastapi

Error:

```
E   sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "***" (::1), port *** failed: FATAL:  database "***" does not exist

   sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "***" (::1), port *** failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "***"
```

I'm trying to do some testing for my fastapi application. I have some test cases. I run my CI/CD using GitHub Actions. I am trying to spin a temporary database inside a container on the GitHub Actions runner.
I am using `pytest` for testing my fastapis.

I have my `conftest.py` placed with my tests folder and that looks like this:

```py
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
import pytest
from app.main import app
from app import schemas ,models
from app.database import Base, get_db
from app.config import settings
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from app.oauth2 import create_access_token


SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL_TEST = f"postgresql://{settings.database_username}:{settings.database_password}@{settings.database_hostname}:{settings.database_port}/fastapi_test"

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL_TEST)

TestingSessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit =False, 
                                autoflush=False, bind=engine)


@pytest.fixture()#scope="module")
def session():
    #run our code before we return our tests
    #print("\n session fixture ran")
    Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
    # run our code after our test finishes
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine) #create tables 
    db = TestingSessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

@pytest.fixture()#(scope="module")
def client(session):
    
    def override_get_db():
      try:
          yield session
      finally:
          session.close()
          #overriding dependency overide get_db with this 
          #Dependency

    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = override_get_db  
    yield TestClient(app)

@pytest.fixture
def test_user_two(client):

    user_data = {"email": "email123.com",
                 "password":"email123"}
    res = client.post("/users/",json = user_data)
    assert res.status_code == 201
    #print(res.json())
    new_user = res.json()
    new_user['password'] = user_data["password"]
    return new_user

@pytest.fixture
def test_user(client):

    user_data = {"email": "email123@ymail.com",
                 "password":"email123"}
    res = client.post("/users/",json = user_data)
    assert res.status_code == 201
    #print(res.json())
    new_user = res.json()
    new_user['password'] = user_data["password"]
    return new_user

@pytest.fixture
def token(test_user):
    return create_access_token({"user_id":test_user["id"]})

@pytest.fixture
def authorized_client(client,token):
    client.headers = {
        **client.headers,
        "Authorization":f"Bearer {token}"
    }

    return client

@pytest.fixture
def test_posts(test_user,session,test_user_two):
    posts_data = [{
        "title" :"secondpost",
        "content":"second post created by user",
        "owner_id":test_user["id"]
        },
        {
        "title" :"pizza places",
        "content":"pizzahut , dominoes",
        "owner_id":test_user["id"]
        },        
        {
        "title" :"third",
        "content":"this is my third post",
        "owner_id":test_user_two["id"]
        }]
    
    def create_posts_model(post):
      return models.Post(**post) 
    
    post_map =  map(create_posts_model,posts_data)
    posts = list(post_map)
    
    session.add_all(posts)
    session.commit()
    posts = session.query(models.Post).all()
    return posts
```

My `deploy.yml` file looks like this:

```yaml
name : Build and Deploy Code

on: [push,pull_request]

jobs : 
  job1: 
    env : 
      DATABASE_HOSTNAME: ${{secrets.DATABASE_HOSTNAME}}
      DATABASE_PORT: ${{secrets.DATABASE_PORT}}
      DATABASE_USERNAME: ${{secrets.DATABASE_USERNAME}}
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.DATABASE_PASSWORD}}
      DATABASE_NAME: fastapi #changed to fastapi_test
      SECRET_KEY: ${{secrets.SECRET_KEY}}
      ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES: ${{secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES}}
      ALGORITHM: ${{secrets.ALGORITHM}}
    services: 
      postgres:
        image: postgres:13
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.DATABASE_PASSWORD}}
          POSTGRES_DB: fastapi_test
          POSTGRES_USER: ${{secrets.DATABASE_USERNAME}}
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5

    runs-on :  ubuntu-latest
    steps : 
      - name : pulling git repo
        uses:  actions/checkout@v2
      - name : say hello to aishwarya
        run : echo "hi aishwarya"
      - name : install python version 3.10
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.10' 
      - name : update pip
        run : python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      - name: install all dependencies
        run : pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name: Print database name
        run: echo $DATABASE_NAME
      - name : test with pytest
        run : | 
            pip install pytest
            pytest -v
```

Initially, I set my DATABASE_NAME: fastapi, postgres db : fastapi_test, SQLALCHEMYURL pointing to fastapi_test.

The CI pipeline failed with error:

```
E   sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "***" (::1), port *** failed: FATAL:  database "***" does not exist.
```

I had to point all three variables to the same database `fastapi_test` in order for it to succeed.

Is this the right way to accomplish it?

Comment: Why do you specifically need PostgreSQL in a container? It's [preinstalled](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#postgresql) on the GitHub Actions runner (`ubuntu-latest`), you just have to start it.

Comment: `POSTGRES_DB` should have the default DB and the env var in your ap should be using the same. See https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres. To make them use the same value, you may configure `POSTGRES_DB` in terms of `DATABASE_NAME` i.e. `POSTGRES_DB: ${{ env.DATABASE_NAME }}`.

Comment: I should have framed my question in a better way. Apologies for that. As you can see I do use a preexisting postgres image and spin up a container using it . I am not installing anything. I did go through the document but I have some doubt that why does my build fail when i use different names in my database_name and postgres_db name?

Comment: Looks like the DB name is hardcoded in `conftest.py` i.e. `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL_TEST = f"postgresql://{settings.database_username}:{settings.database_password}@{settings.database_hostname}:{settings.database_port}/fastapi_test"`

Comment: For that hardcoded DB name i.e. `fastapi_test`, the DB must be created before use. Configuring `POSTGRES_DB` with the required DB name creates the DB when PostgreSQL starts. Otherwise, the tests depending on DB would fail.

Comment: When i checked github actions , it mentions that the database container is up and running before the tests are executed!

Comment: DB container should start with and without the correct default DB. Regarding your question "**Is this the right way to accomplish it?**", my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76232012/getting-an-error-while-trying-to-run-postgresql-in-container-on-github-actions-r?noredirect=1#comment134436362_76232012) comment should address it that all the variables (i.e. default DB name and the DB name for your app) should have the same value which you can specify using `env.DATABASE_NAME`. In app source, you may fetch it from env var instead of hardcoding it.

Answer (score 0):

The example in this question comes from a fast API course on youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sOvCWFmrtA&t=65833s

I was following it and ran into same issue.

The issue is that in our main file we have below statement which expects a DB name 'fastapi' from database.py file

```
models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

In your yml file you are creating database with name fastapi_test, so it doesnt find fastapi and hence errors out

```
env:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.DATABASE_PASSWORD}}
      POSTGRES_DB: fastapi_test
      POSTGRES_USER: ${{secrets.DATABASE_USERNAME}}
```

**Solution1: Tested and Works fine for me**

Keep the database name `POSTGRES_DB: fastapi` in yml file as we only need one database for the test and don't need an additional fastapi_test database

```
env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.DATABASE_PASSWORD}}
          POSTGRES_DB: fastapi
          POSTGRES_USER: ${{secrets.DATABASE_USERNAME}}
```

additionally you need to set a new Env variable `TEST_DATABASE_NAME=fastapi_test` and need to set it everwhere in .env file , config.py and in confest.py url should be:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DB_URL = (f'postgresql://'
                     f'{settings.database_username}:{settings.database_password}'
                     f'@{settings.database_hostname}:{settings.database_port}'
                     f'/{settings.test_database_name}')
```

**Solution2: Not tested but should work fine**

Keep the same yml file but Comment below line in main.py. This will prevent auto-creation of new tables but if you are running alembic migration this may not be required.

```
models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

the GitHub link to the course has same line commented out